# HTML 5 Remote Notification without opening pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, notifications

My system is OS X 10.10 going with latest Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and Safari.  I've implemented a HTML5 web site with remote notification pushed from my server by Pusher API. However, it can only run when my web site is opening. Some web sites such as 9to5mac, TechCrunch, can push me remote notification even the web sites are not opening on my browsers.

How do they implement it?
Background running? Web socket?
Appreciate anyone who answer my questions.

Comment: chrome just added an API using serviceWorkers , http://venturebeat.com/2015/04/14/chrome-42-launches-with-push-notifications-that-sites-can-send-even-after-users-close-the-page/ it's really complicated, but it can trigger notifications that appear even if your tabs/browser are closed.

Comment: Does it only supports Chrome?
9to5mac and TechCrunch can both push notification to my Safari and Firefox.